# Why do we need to study closed systems if no real mechanical system is actually closed?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I am taking a course in Classical Mechanics. We were discussing on the importance of closed systems. Is it really possible to break down every system of concern into separate closed systems? I think maybe yes but I am really not sure if the corresponding subsystems will be independent or not. And the problem I find is that when we are trying to study a general system, there will always be a time dependence when we write Lagrangian. How do we understand that which subsystem should be made time dependent and which and which one be made time independent?
Sorry for being too vague. I would be helped to have a general discussion if not a mathematical description.

Comment: Hi Adam Gilchrist. Welcome to Phys.SE. Do you know the difference between implicit and explicit time dependence?

Comment: When the Lagrangian has direct time dependence it must be explicit. Otherwise it is dependent on coordinates which are always time dependent. Am I right?

Comment: The answer is the same as to why we study linear systems so much when the majority of the systems in real life are non-linear. Because it's easier to do. Because we can develop useful tools to study them and then try to move to “slightly open systems”